# Filtering pandas dataframe on condition over NaN

Tags: pandas

I have a datetime dataframe in pandas like this:

```
                 date  value1  value2 name
0  2020-08-27 07:30:00    28.0    27.0    A
1  2020-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
2  2020-08-27 09:00:00    NaN     27.5    A
3  2020-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    A
4  2020-08-27 10:30:00    NaN      NaN    A
5  2020-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
6  2020-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
7  2020-08-27 12:00:00    30.0    27.0    A
8  2020-08-27 12:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
9  2020-08-27 13:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
10  2020-08-27 07:30:00    28.0    27.0    B
11  2020-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    B
12  2020-08-27 09:00:00    NaN     27.5    B
13  2020-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    B
14  2020-08-27 10:30:00    NaN      NaN    B
15  2020-08-27 11:00:00    29.8     NaN    B
16  2020-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    B
17  2020-08-27 12:00:00    30.0    27.0    B
18  2020-08-27 12:30:00    30.0    27.0    B
19  2020-08-27 13:30:00    30.0    27.0    B
```

I wish to remove entry for all name for which number of NaN in any column is 3 or more. I am able to calculate NaN in each column.

```
df.drop('name', 1).isna().groupby(df.name, sort=False).sum().reset_index()
```

How can I use this to filter df:

My expected output is:

```
               date  value1  value2 name
0  2020-08-27 07:30:00    28.0    27.0    A
1  2020-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
2  2020-08-27 09:00:00    NaN     27.5    A
3  2020-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    A
4  2020-08-27 10:30:00    NaN      NaN    A
5  2020-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
6  2020-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
7  2020-08-27 12:00:00    30.0    27.0    A
8  2020-08-27 12:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
9  2020-08-27 13:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df.set_index("name") \
      .loc[df[["value1", "value2"]] \
             .isna() \
             .groupby(df["name"]) \
             .sum() \
             .max(axis="columns") < 3]

                    date  value1  value2
name
A    2020-08-27 07:30:00    28.0    27.0
A    2020-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0
A    2020-08-27 09:00:00     NaN    27.5
A    2020-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN
A    2020-08-27 10:30:00     NaN     NaN
A    2020-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0
A    2020-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0
A    2020-08-27 12:00:00    30.0    27.0
A    2020-08-27 12:30:00    30.0    27.0
A    2020-08-27 13:30:00    30.0    27.0
```